# Java collection, generics and abstract class: concrete class information lost

Tags: java, generics, abstract

I have class `Bar` (and potentially a number of other classes) which extends abstract class `AbstractFoo`. When converting an instance of `Bar` to `FooDTO`, the concrete class is detected.

However, when converting a collection of `Bar` instances to a list of `FooDTO`, the concrete class information is lost, and conversion is performed on the basis of `AbstractFoo`.

What's going wrong here?

```
public class CollectionGenericsNGTest {


    public static abstract class AbstractFoo { }

    public static class Bar extends AbstractFoo { }

    public static class FooDTO {
        final boolean isBar;

        public FooDTO(AbstractFoo f) {
            this.isBar = false;
        }

        public FooDTO(Bar b) {
            this.isBar = true;
        }
    }

    public static class FooDTOList {
        List<FooDTO> list;

        public FooDTOList(Collection<? extends AbstractFoo> source) {
            list = source.stream()
                    .map(entry -> new FooDTO(entry))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        public List<FooDTO> getList() {
            return list;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testDTO() {
        Bar b = new Bar();
        FooDTO f = new FooDTO(b);

        assertTrue(f.isBar);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDTO_abstract() {
        AbstractFoo b = new Bar();
        FooDTO f = new FooDTO(b);

        assertTrue(f.isBar); // <-- fails, too
    }

    @Test
    public void testDTOList() {
        Bar b = new Bar();
        List<Bar> collection = Arrays.asList(b);
        FooDTOList list = new FooDTOList(collection);

        FooDTO f = list.getList().get(0);
        assertTrue(f.isBar); // <--- this fails!
    }

}
```

Comment: You are dealing with type erasure: https://beust.com/weblog/2011/07/29/erasure-vs-reification/

Comment: Can you try to make b in testDTO of type AbstractFoo? I would assume that that test should also break then, even though b is really a Bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
.map(entry -> new FooDTO(entry))
```

you are *always* calling

```
new FooDTO(AbstractFoo)
```

the constructor which sets `this.isBar` to false.

Even if the object held by `entry` has run-time type `Bar`, the variable `entry` has type `AbstractFoo`, because it is part of a `Collection<? extends AbstractFoo>`, so the compiler knows the object must be an `AbstractFoo`, but doesn't know it is a `Bar`. Overload resolution works on the type of the reference at compile-type, not the type of the object at run-time.

If you want to check the run-time type of the object held by `entry`, instead of the variable type, you might consider using

```
this.isBar = (f instanceof Bar);
```

when you assign to your field. That will check the run-time type of the actual object referenced by `f`.

---

In your simpler case

```
Bar b = new Bar();
FooDTO f = new FooDTO(b);
```

the constructor call is resolved to `new FooDTO(Bar)` because you are passing it a reference of type `Bar`.

If you instead had:

```
AbstractFoo b = new Bar();
FooDTO f = new FooDTO(b);
```

then the constructor call would resolve to `new FooDTO(AbstractFoo)`, because you would be passing a reference of type `AbtractFoo`.

Comment: Link which supports your answer: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/15au/java/subtypes.html